# JQuery Copy Selected Select option to input

Tags: jquery

I have a select:

```
<select>
   <option value="Peter">Peter</option>
   <option value="James">James</option>
</select>

<input type="text" value="" />
```

I need to copy the value of the selected option in the select to the input value.

How can I do this using jquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this script:

```
$("select").on("change", function () {    //when selected value changed
    $("input[type=text]").val($(this).val());  //change value in textbox
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
 $('input[type="text"]').val($('select').val());
```